# avatservice returns nullpointer exception in JIRA 6.4

Tags: jira-plugin

For our project tab panel plugin, we are using `AvatarService` to show avatar of the assigned user for an issue. Until 6.3.9 it was working fine, but now after upgrading to 6.4.1 it seems to break and throws null pointer exception.

I'm obtaining `AvatarService` from `TabPanel` class's constructor and passing it to velocity in params.

But when the tab panel is loaded I get this error in the page's source:
`org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getAvatarUrlNoPermCheck' in  class com.atlassian.jira.avatar.AvatarServiceImpl threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException at shared/Panel.vm.`

What could be wrong? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/How+to+fix+the+getAvatarUrlNoPermCheck+Exception+in+Notifications) it may be the same root cause:

> The Base URL has been improperly specified.
>
> Confirm that the Base URL in Configuring JIRA Options is the exact
>   same URL that you use to access the JIRA instance.